# ASP.NET Core 1.0 on IIS error 502.5 - Error Code 0x80004005

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, iis, windows-server-2012-r2

I just updated my server (Windows 2012R2) to .NET Core 1.0 RTM Windows Hosting pack from the previous .NET Core 1.0 RC2. My app works on **my PC** without any issues but the server keeps showing:

```
HTTP Error 502.5 - Process Failure


Common causes of this issue:

The application process failed to start
The application process started but then stopped
The application process started but failed to listen on the configured port
```

It previously worked with the RC2 version. Don't know what could go wrong.

This is all event viewer says:

> Failed to start process with the commandline 'dotnet .\MyWebApp.dll'. Error code = '0x80004005'.

the worst part is that app logs are **empty!** I mean those stdout_xxxxxxxxx.log files are completely empty and all have 0 byte size.

What should I do?? How can I know the cause of error when it's not logged??

Comment: Possibly related? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37362183/bad-gateway-error-when-loading-aspnetcore-rc2-default-website-project

Comment: How is it related? Error code is clearly different. Let alone the fact that I said it works on my own PC with IIS.

Comment: First, I said **possibly** related, since mentions that `Failed to start process with commandline 'dotnet ./bin/Debug/netcoreapp1.0/WebApplication2.dll', Error Code = '0x80004005'.` - the same commandline and error code that you are reporting.  Secondly, just because it runs on your machine, but not the remote machine, indicates that something is different on the server.  If you could expand on how the application is deployed to the server, that would be helpful.

Comment: what do you mean your app working on your pc.. you mean you have a project deploying to iis? am i ryt?

Comment: Yes. It works on IIS on my PC but not on the server

Comment: Did u migrate your project to RTM ?

Comment: Is there any output to the console is you run command line (starting in the publish directory) 'dotnet .\MyWebApp.dll'? Does the runtimes directory have the correct architecture runtime included?

Comment: Did you set your app pool's .NET CLR version to No Managed Code?

Comment: @HamidMosalla, Yes. It's set to `No Managed Code`

Comment: @VSG24 Did you see this section of asp.net doc? [Publishing to IIS](https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/publishing/iis.html#common-errors), it lists common errors and has a couple of reasons listed for 502.5 error.

Comment: I had the same problem on Windows Server 2012 R2 Standard edition. After try alot of ways: restart IIS, install NET Core SDK, add configuration tag in web.config... but it's not solve the problem. Follow Vahid Amiri, I install Microsoft Visual C++ 2015 Redistributable Update 3 (https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=53840). It's work very well!

Comment: If you are using windows please follow the step @hosein dafeyan define and make sure you are using correct version of .Net Hosting for .net core depends on what version of .net core you are using. for e.g if you are working on .net 2.1.1 so you need to install .Net Hosting 2.1.1 in you machine or where the site is deployed.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

So I got a new server, this time it's Windows 2008R2 and my app works fine.

I can't say for sure what the problem was with the old server but I have one idea.

So because I previously compiled the app **without** any platform in mind it gave me the `dll` version which only works if the target host has `.Net Core Windows Hosting` package installed. In my case it was **installed and that was fine**.

After the app didn't work I decieded to compile it as a console app with `win7-x64` as runtime. This time the moment I ran the `exe` of my app on the server, it crashed with an error about a missing dll:

```
The program can't start because api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll is missing
```

That dll is from Universal C Runtime that's included in the **Visual C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio 2015**.

I tried to install that package (both x64 & x86) but it failed each time (don't know why) on Windows Server 2012 R2.

But when I tried to install them in the new server, Windows Server 2008 R2, they successfully installed. That might have been the reason behind it, but still can't say for sure.

Answer (score 115):

I was able to fix it by running

> "C:\Program Files\dotnet\dotnet.exe" "C:\fullpath\PROJECT.dll"

on the command prompt, which gave me a much more meaningful error:

> "The specified framework 'Microsoft.NETCore.App', version '1.0.1' was
>   not found.
>     - Check application dependencies and target a framework version installed at:
>         C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App
>     - The following versions are installed:
>         1.0.0
>     - Alternatively, install the framework version '1.0.1'.

As you can see, I had the wrong NET Core version installed on my server. I was able to run my application after uninstalling the previous version 1.0.0 and installing the correct version 1.0.1.

Comment: I managed to use this to find I needed NodeJS installed...  as it does give a "much more meaningful message".

Comment: I cant tell you how much time i wasted on this. Thank you. My error was relating to a missing cert. Why couldnt I get this error through some sane method?

Comment: This worked for me, I could see an exception barfed out on the command line, which got me moving.  Much obliged.

Comment: I also had wrong .net core version installed, the one that appears on the official microsoft [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/publishing/iis) for iis hosting is .net core 2.0 and I had my project built under 1.1.2. Old .net core releases are available [here](https://github.com/dotnet/core/blob/master/release-notes/download-archive.md).

Comment: Can someone please tell me what the command is? What is C:\fullpath\dotnet  ??  The path to your app, but what is *dotnet*? There are no dotnet file in the project folder

Comment: @JeremyThompson it's the path of the dotnet.exe which is normally located at : C:\Program Files\dotnet\dotnet.exe

Comment: I just had to update the nuget package for Microsoft.AspNetCore.App to the same version that was installed on my system. Facepalm

Comment: I just came across this error after an update to .NET CORE 2.1.3 fixed it by installing the right .NET SDK/runtime.

Answer (score 68):

I had the same problem, in my case it was insufficient permission of the user identity of my Application Pool, on [Publishing to IIS](https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/publishing/iis.html#common-errors) page of asp.net doc, there is a couple of reason listed for this error:

- If you published a self-contained application, confirm that you didn’t set a platform in `buildOptions` of `project.json` that conflicts with the publishing RID. For example, do not specify a platform of x86 and publish with an RID of win81-x64 (`dotnet publish -c Release -r win81-x64`). The project will publish without warning or error but fail with the above logged exceptions on the server.
- Check the `processPath` attribute on the `<aspNetCore>` element in web.config to confirm that it is `dotnet` for a portable application or .\my_application.exe for a self-contained application.
- For a portable application, `dotnet.exe` might not be accessible via the PATH settings. Confirm that `C:\Program Files\dotnet\` exists in the System PATH settings.
- For a portable application, `dotnet.exe` might not be accessible for the user identity of the Application Pool. Confirm that the AppPool user identity has access to the `C:\Program Files\dotnet` directory.
- Confirm that you have correctly referenced the IIS Integration middleware by calling the `.UseIISIntegration()` method of the application’s `WebHostBuilder()`.
- If you are using the `.UseUrls()` extension method when self-hosting with Kestrel, confirm that it is positioned before the `.UseIISIntegration()` extension method on `WebHostBuilder()`. `.UseIISIntegration()` must set the `Url` for the reverse-proxy when running Kestrel behind IIS and not have its value overridden by `.UseUrls()`.

In my case it was the fourth reason, I changed it by right clicking my app pool, and in advanced setting under Process Model, I set the Identity to a user with enough permission:
[image: user identity of my Application Pool]

Comment: This is the Answer i was looking for!, in my case it was the application pool too....

Comment: Thank you. In my case the problem was with path to dotnet. Found such logs in system Event Viewer: `Failed to start process with commandline '"dotnet" .\PROJECT.dll', ErrorCode = '0x80070002'`.

Comment: I would add another reason: "Installer unable to obtain VC++ Redistributable" since my server has no internet connection, it couldn't download this package... Hence, you have to manually download it: [link](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=53840) and install it.

Comment: `dotnet` was in my path, but required a restart of the server for it to be recognised.

Comment: in my case i have to specify --runtime value in publish command if i provide --framework option otherwise DO NOT give --framework and it is figuring out the runtime by default.

Comment: Please, do NOT give any web application System account permissions. Rather set IIS_IUSRS permission to execute for the website directory.

Comment: I changed the processPath to "C:\Program Files\dotnet\dotnet.exe" as the PATH environment var was not set for System (a restart may have fixed this).

Answer (score 67):

I got this working with a hard reset of IIS (I had only just installed the hosting package).

Turns out that just pressing 'Restart' in IIS Manager isn't enough. I just had to open a command prompt and type 'iisreset'

Comment: I also pressed the green recycle iis at the webserver root node in the UI. This solved it for me combined with the user setting for the app pool to `LocalSystem`

Comment: Thanks Michael... This solved my problem too. Had been looking for an answer for a couple of hours. Thank you!

Comment: Tx! Your answer reminded me of this from ms docs "Restart the system or execute **net stop was /y** followed by **net start w3svc** from a command prompt to pick up a change to the system PATH." (after installing .NET Core Windows Server Hosting bundle)

Comment: Solved my problem too. Thanks

Comment: Worked for me. Thanks :)

Comment: this solved my issue, I installed all software on server one by one, but may be not take reference. when I restarted IIS, it works.... Bingo.

Answer (score 6):

I had the same issue when publishing the web app.
If anybody still has this problem fixed it by changing **{AppName}.runtimeconfig.json**

```
    {
  "runtimeOptions": {
    "framework": {
      "name": "Microsoft.NETCore.App",
      "version": "1.1.2"
    },
    "configProperties": {
      "System.GC.Server": true
    }
  }
}
```

Change the version from **"version": "1.1.2"** to **"version": "1.1.1"** and everythign worked ok

Answer (score 6):

I had the same problem.

To find out the exact source of it I switched on logging in
web.config file:

```
<aspNetCore processPath="dotnet" arguments=".\MyWebService.dll" stdoutLogEnabled="**true**" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" />
```

and created logs subfolder in MyWebService root folder.

After restarting IIS and trying to execute API I got an error and it was missing of proper Core Runtime. After downloading an installing DotNetCore.1.0.5_1.1.2-WindowsHosting the error gone.

Comment: IMO you should remove the asterisks from the 'true' value to avoid any confusion.

Answer (score 4):

Had the same issue and all solutions didn't work.  Found this gem and thought I'd pass along if it helps someone else.  Install on Server 2012 R2 getting the DLL missing error, try to reinstall VS C++ 2015 and get an error.  Fix is to do the following:

Seems the file 
`C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\...\packages\Patch\x64\Windows8.1-KB2999226-x64.msu` has problems being installed. 
Open admin command prompt do:

```
c:
mkdir tmp
mkdir tmp\tmp
move "C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\...\packages\Patch\x64\Windows8.1-KB2999226-x64.msu" c:\tmp
expand -F:* c:\tmp\Windows8.1-KB2999226-x64.msu c:\tmp\tmp
dism /online /add-package /packagepath:c:\tmp\tmp\Windows8.1-KB2999226-x64.cab
```

NOTE: replace the "..." with the correct folder name.  After this reinstall the VS C++ 2015 package.

Answer (score 4):

I had a similar issue, and to quote Sherlock Holmes:
"*when you have eliminated the impossible, whatever remains, however improbable, must be the truth?*"

I checked if the .NET framework I was targeting was installed on the server, and it turns out it wasn't. I installed the 4.6.2 .NET Framework and it worked.

Answer (score 4):

I got this issue on my production server after my VS project was automatically upgraded to .NET Core 1.1.2.

I simply installed the 1.1.2 .net core runtime from here on my production server: https://www.microsoft.com/net/download/core#/runtime

Comment: I ran across the same issue but with the newly released net core 2.0.6. Fixed by installing net core SDK 2.0.6 on a production server

Answer (score 4):

**SOLVED** I just ran through the same issue today while deploying to **AZURE**. Then I tried the same for local IIS, got the same issue. As I am new to .net CORE, struggled few hour before I actually solved it.

In our solution, after I publish to IIS, I observed my web.confile file, specially below line `<aspNetCore processPath="bin\IISSupport\VSIISExeLauncher.exe" arguments="-argFile IISExeLauncherArgs.txt" forwardWindowsAuthToken="false" stdoutLogEnabled="false" />`

In our deployment folder the generated web.config looks like:`<aspNetCore processPath="dotnet" arguments=".\Yodlee.dll -argFile IISExeLauncherArgs.txt" forwardWindowsAuthToken="false" stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" />`

**Now PLEASE try changing the above configuration in visual studio solution to**`<aspNetCore processPath="bin\IISSupport\VSIISExeLauncher.exe" forwardWindowsAuthToken="false" stdoutLogEnabled="false" />`

**In our new deployment folder the generated web.config looks like:**`<aspNetCore processPath="dotnet" arguments=".\Yodlee.dll" forwardWindowsAuthToken="false" stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" />`

And This SOLVED my problem, Hope it help.

Comment: Hey @Agni, this worked for me, thanks. But, every time I try to publish the project again to Azure, it gets rebuilt, and the web.config is automatically changed back to the original one, with the part that causes the problem: "-argFile IISExeLauncherArgs.txt". Did you find a solution for that? (I'm using asp.net core 2.0).

Comment: in my case I had to change `processPath="dotnet"` to `processPath="C:\Program Files\dotnet\dotnet.exe"`. then it worked.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem when I updated my dev machine to Core 1.0.1, but forgot to update the server.

Comment: For me I reinstalled the net core SDK from here: https://www.microsoft.com/net/core#windows

then it worked.

Comment: VS2017 is now .NET Core 1.1 by default - all remote servers need to be updated before publishing upgraded projs to IIS. You can get the more helpful error message (".NET core 1.1 not installed") but running `dotnet .\YOURPROJDLL.dll`

Answer (score 3):

I was getting HTTP Error 502.5 while trying to publish my .NET Core 2.0 API to AWS EB, and solved it by adding the following code to the .csproj:

```
  <PropertyGroup>
    <PublishWithAspNetCoreTargetManifest>false</PublishWithAspNetCoreTargetManifest>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

Answer (score 2):

I had a same issue . I changed application pool identity to network service account . Then I explicitly set the path to dotnet.exe in the web.config for the application to work properly as @danielyewright said in his [github](https://github.com/aspnet/Hosting/issues/844) comment . It works after set the path.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Sharing that in my case this error was because i forgot to update **project.json** with:

```
"buildOptions": {
    "emitEntryPoint": true
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

I had the same error in question, with the same issues as described by VSG24 in Proposed answer - nasty error message when typing 'dotnet' into CMD:

> The program can't start because api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll is missing

I solved this by manually installing the following 2 updates on **Windows Server 2012 R2** (and the pre-requisites and all the other updates linked - read the installation instructions carefully on the Microsoft website):

> 1. KB2919355
> 2. KB2999226

Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 2):

I faced the same issue when I tried to publish Debug version of my web application. This set of files didn't contain the file `web.config` with the proper value of attribute `processPath`.

I took this file from Release version, value was assigned to the path to my exe file.

```
<aspNetCore processPath=".\My.Web.App.exe" ... />
```

Answer (score 2):

In my case was problem with Net Core version installed on server.
I just install the same version as on my development machine and everything is OK :-)

Answer (score 2):

Here is what I figured, and this happened recently on Windows 10 after an update was installed. From what I gathered, a Windows Defender update was installed which assumed my "Project.dll"(an asp.net core project) behaved like a virus so it was deleted.

So, one of the first things I suggest you do before you start installing/uninstalling stuffs is to check to **confirm your "Project.dll" is where it should be.**

Copy it back to the location if it is no longer there.

If you are **having difficulty copying the file back add an exclusion to your project folder in windows defender**. ( [Learn how to do that here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4028485/windows-10-add-an-exclusion-to-windows-defender-antivirus). )

This worked for me instantly, and I repeated it across application multiple servers.

Answer (score 2):

In my case, after installing `AspNetCore.2.0.6.RuntimePackageStore_x64.exe` and `DotNetCore.2.0.6-WindowsHosting.exe` , I need to **restart server** to make it worked without 502 bad gateway and proxy error.

UPDATE:

There is a way you could use it without restart:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/50808634/3634867

Answer (score 2):

I needed to install the latest .net Core version found [here](https://www.microsoft.com/net/download/windows#/runtime).
No need to restart the site or server

Answer (score 2):

I solved it by adding "edit permission" to the application of the site, mapped to the physical directory and then selected the windows user that could have access to this root folder. (private network).

Answer (score 2):

Open **command prompt** with **Administrator** credentials

Type following command and hit enter

> >  **IISRESET**

OR

Open **Visual Studio 2017** with **Administrator** credentials

Type following command in **Package Manager Console** and hit enter

> *PM*>  **IISRESET**

```
PM> IISRESET
Attempting stop...
Internet services successfully stopped
Attempting start...
Internet services successfully restarted
```

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem aswell (The error occurred both on VS 15 and 17). However on VS15 it returned a `CONNECTION_REFUSED` error and on VS17 it returned `ASP.NET Core 1.0 on IIS error 502.5`.

**FIX**

1. Navigate to your project directory and locate the hidden folder `.vs` (it's located in the projects folder dir). (Remember to show hidden files/folders)
2. Close VS
3. Delete .vs-folder
4. Start VS as admin (.vs-folder will be recreated by VS)

Answer (score 1):

For me it was that the connectionString in Startup.cs was null in:

```
services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
```

and it was null because the application was not looking into appsettings.json for the connection string.

Had to change Program.cs to:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    BuildWebHost(args).Run();
}

public static IWebHost BuildWebHost(string[] args) =>
     WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
     .ConfigureAppConfiguration((context, builder) => builder.SetBasePath(context.HostingEnvironment.ContentRootPath)
     .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json").Build())
     .UseStartup<Startup>().Build();
```

Answer (score 1):

I have no idea why this worked for me, but I am using Windows Authentication and I had this bit of code on my `BuildWebHost` in `Program.cs`:

```
.UseStartup<Startup>()
.UseHttpSys(options =>
{
    options.Authentication.Schemes =
        AuthenticationSchemes.NTLM | AuthenticationSchemes.Negotiate;
    options.Authentication.AllowAnonymous = false;
})
.Build();
```

After removing the `.UserHttpSys` bit, it now works, and I can still authenticate as a domain user.

`BuildWebHost` now looks like

```
public static IWebHost BuildWebHost(string[] args) =>
    WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
    .UseStartup<Startup>()
    .Build();
```

Comment: I am having cookie authentication in aspnet core. How do I configure?

Comment: @kudlatiger Sorry I'm not sure - your best bet is to create a seperate question

Answer (score 1):

I was getting the same error, and found out the problem was that during the publish to Azure, my **web.config** file was modified so this following line ended up like this:

```
<aspNetCore processPath="bin\IISSupport\VSIISExeLauncher.exe" arguments="-argFile IISExeLauncherArgs.txt" forwardWindowsAuthToken="false" stdoutLogEnabled="false" startupTimeLimit="3600" requestTimeout="23:00:00" />
```

The problem **for Production** are the contents of the arguments: **"-argFile IISExeLauncherArgs.txt"**

It seems like this issue is going to be addressed in the next .NET Core SDK (currently in preview), but for now, the workaround is to add this block to the .csproj file:

```
<Target Name="bug_242_workaround" AfterTargets="_TransformWebConfig">
    <Exec Command="powershell &quot;(Get-Content '$(PublishDir)Web.config').replace(' -argFile IISExeLauncherArgs.txt', '') | Set-Content '$(PublishDir)Web.config'&quot;" />
  </Target>
```

This will modify the web.config and remove the problematic part for publishing.

Reference: https://github.com/aspnet/websdk/issues/242

Hope it helps.

Comment: Both startupTimeLimit & requestTimeout attribs being added appears to be a [tooling bug](https://github.com/aspnet/Home/issues/2993).

Answer (score 1):

Worked for me after changing the publishing configuration.

[image]

Comment: Sorry I cannot see images in my organization.  The images download are blocked (on most organization).

Answer (score 1):

For me it was caused by having different versions of .Net Core installed. I matched my dev and production server and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue (Asp.Net Core 2.x) that was caused by trying to run a 32-bit asp.net core app in IIS on a 64-bit windows server. The root cause was that the web.config that is auto-generated (if your project does not explicitly include one, which asp.net core projects do not by default) does not contain the full path to the dotnet executable. When you install the hosting bundle on a 64 bit machine it will install the 64 and 32 bit versions of dotnet, but the path will resolve by default to 64 bit and your 32 bit asp.net core app will fail to load. In your browser you may see a 502.5 error and if you look the server event log you might see error code 0x80004005. If you try to run dotnet.exe from a command prompt to load your asp.net core application dll on that server you may see an error like "BadImageFormatException" or "attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format". The fix that worked for me was to add a web.config to my project (and deployment) and in that web.config set the full path to the 32-bit version of dotnet.exe.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <location path="." inheritInChildApplications="false">
        <system.webServer>
            <handlers>
                <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModule" resourceType="Unspecified" />
            </handlers>
            <aspNetCore processPath="C:\Program Files (x86)\dotnet\dotnet.exe" arguments=".\My32BitAspNetCoreApp.dll" stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" />
       </system.webServer>
   </location>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem and the reason in my case was that the EF core was trying to read connection string from `appsettings.development.json` file. I opened it and found the connection string was commented.

```
//{
//  "ConnectionStrings": {
//    "DefaultConnection": "Server=vaio;Database=Goldentaurus;Trusted_Connection=True;",
//    "IdentityConnection": "Server=vaio;Database=GTIdentity;Trusted_Connection=True;"
//  }
//}
```

I then uncommitted them like below and the problem solved:

```
{
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "DefaultConnection": "Server=vaio;Database=Goldentaurus;Trusted_Connection=True;",
    "IdentityConnection": "Server=vaio;Database=GTIdentity;Trusted_Connection=True;"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I changed profile options to this and it's working!!!

[image]

Maybe you should change this two options:

1. *Deployment Mode*
2. *Target Runtime*

Comment: When I do that my style is not apply any solution about this ?