# ASP.Net core failed to publish on IIS. Error 502.5: 0x80004005 : c0000135

Tags: iis, asp.net-core

Good morning,

I have developed a new ASP.Net Core website published using VS 2015 which works in preprod when published on on my local IIS but not when published on my company IIS Server.
With my IT administrator, we've been through all the different steps listed here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/publishing/iis and tried the solutions: [ASP.NET Core 1.0 on IIS error 502.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38624453/asp-net-core-1-0-on-iis-error-502-5)

- Install the ASP.Net core windows hosting bundle 1.1.0 which appears
  in the modules now
- Restart IIS
- Check that dotnet.exe is    accessible for the user    identity
  of the Application Pool
- Check that    dotnet.exe is accessible in the PATH settings
- Check that    `.UseIISIntegration()` is my program.cs

but we still have an error

```
failed to start process with commandline '"dotnet" .\WebApplication.dll', ErrorCode = '0x80004005 : c0000135.
```

My Web.config is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModule" resourceType="Unspecified" />
    </handlers>
    <aspNetCore processPath="dotnet" arguments=".\WebApplication3.dll" stdoutLogEnabled="true" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" forwardWindowsAuthToken="false" />
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

My appsettings.json:

```
{
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "DefaultConnection": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
  },
  "Logging": {
    "IncludeScopes": false,
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Debug",
      "System": "Information",
      "Microsoft": "Information"
    }
  }
}
```

and my project.json:

```
    {
  "userSecretsId": "aspnet-WebApplication3-XXX",

  "dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Tools": {
      "version": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
      "type": "build"
    },
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools": {
      "version": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
      "type": "build"
    },
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Tools": {
      "version": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
      "type": "build"
    },
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGenerators.Mvc": {
      "version": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
      "type": "build"
    },
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.EntityFrameworkCore": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc": "1.1.1",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Design": {
      "version": "1.1.0",
      "type": "build"
    },
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.EnvironmentVariables": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.UserSecrets": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Options.ConfigurationExtensions": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.NETCore.App": {
      "version": "1.1.0",
      "type": "platform"
    },
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.BrowserLink.Loader": "14.1.0"
  },

  "tools": {
    "BundlerMinifier.Core": "2.2.306",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Tools": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration.Tools": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.SecretManager.Tools": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Tools": {
      "version": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
      "imports": [
        "portable-net45+win8"
      ]
    }
  },

  "frameworks": {
    "netcoreapp1.1": {
      "imports": [
        "dotnet5.6",
        "portable-net45+win8"
      ]
    }
  },

  "buildOptions": {
    "emitEntryPoint": true,
    "preserveCompilationContext": true
  },

  "runtimeOptions": {
    "configProperties": {
      "System.GC.Server": true
    }
  },

  "publishOptions": {
    "include": [
      "wwwroot",
      "**/*.cshtml",
      "appsettings.json",
      "web.config"
    ]
  },
  "scripts": {
    "prepublish": [ "bower install", "dotnet bundle" ],
    "postpublish": [ "dotnet publish-iis --publish-folder %publish:OutputPath% --framework %publish:FullTargetFramework%" ]
  }
}
```

Would you have other suggestions? What would the c0000135 suggests?

Cheers

Sylvain

Comment: Did asp.net register to your IIS Server? Is Directory Browsing enabled?

Comment: Thanks @mark-spencer, I tried your tips but no success, i have also updated my app to use Microsoft.NETCore.App 1.1.0 to be in line with the  ASP.Net core windows hosting bundle 1.1.0 installed on IIS but still the 502.5 error....

Comment: I would try running the website from the command line using dotnet on that machine also. If that runs then you have a problem with the net framework or permissions on your machine.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error, fixed by installing [Microsoft Visual C++ 2015 Redistributable Update 3](https://www.microsoft.com/download/details.aspx?id=52685).

After that I got another error:

> Failed to load the dll from [?9], HRESULT: 0x80070057
>
> The library hostfxr.dll was found, but loading it from C:\Program Files\dotnet\host\fxr\2.0.7\hostfxr.dll failed

Installed [KB2999226](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2999226/update-for-universal-c-runtime-in-windows) and [KB3118401](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/3118401/update-for-universal-c-runtime-in-windows) - it did not help. I use Windows Server 2008 R2.

[Prerequisites for .NET Core on Windows](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/windows-prerequisites?tabs=netcore2x)

Comment: Installing KB2999226 & KB2533623 helped me overcome this issue. Hope it helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

To solve it I added these lines to the .csproj file

```
<PropertyGroup>
       <PublishWithAspNetCoreTargetManifest>false</PublishWithAspNetCoreTargetManifest>
</PropertyGroup>
```

This works for me.