# HTTP Error 502.5 - Process Failure when application is run from Visual Studio

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2015, asp.net-core

I've seen [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38624453/asp-net-core-1-0-on-iis-error-502-5), but it is not my case cause I run my project from Visual Studio. It is not a deployed application.

I've recently installed *Visual Studio 2015 Professional Update 3* and I am running **locally** *ASP.NET Core Web with AngularJS 2* application.
What I see is error when I run application is:

> HTTP Error 502.5 - Process Failure
>
> Common causes of this issue:
>
> The application process failed to start The application process
>
> started but then stopped The application process started but failed to
>
> listen on the configured port

I've already installed the follwing packages at my PC:

1. DotNetCore.1.0.0-VS2015Tools.Preview 2
2. DotNetCore.1.0.1-VS2015Tools.Preview2.0.3
3. DotNetCore.1.0.4_1.1.1-WindowsHosting
4. dotnet-dev-win-x64.1.0.1
5. dotnet-win-x64.1.1.1

Does anybody know how can I resolve this error?

Comment: Which is the configured port ? It may be out of the available range or already be used. Did this error appeared the first time you ran the app ?

Comment: Do you have a web server already running ? (IIS, IIS-Express, Apache, Glassfish, etc.)

Comment: @AlexandreNourissier how can I know whether the port is available? Yeah, IIS Express is run by Visual Studio when I start the application.

Comment: netstat -a -b -n

Comment: Did you try running VS with administrative rights?

Comment: @fofik yeah, I tried to run with administrative rights.

Comment: It started and immediately stopped? Check app pool identity credentials?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That was my silly mistake.  **I should just not run my application immediately, but at first try to debug my application!**

When I tried to debug my application, then I saw the following exception:

> Can't load Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting 1.1.0.0

Then I just corrected dependencies `project.json` file and it started working very well.

Thanks a lot, guys, to all!