# asp core net C:\Program Files\dotnet\dotnet.exe

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core

Every time after publishing my project to iis i need to change in the web config the `processPath` attribute from `processPath="dotnet.exe"` to `processPath="C:\Program Files\dotnet\dotnet.exe"` to start my program.

I know that i can add this attribute/parameter to my project, but i don't know how. In my project i have not a web file config. The config file as i understand is created automaticaaly when i publish my project.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just add path of dotnet.exe to Environment variable Path

```
This PC -> Properties -> Advanced system settings -> Environment Variables... -> System variables -> Path -> Edit -> New -> C:\Program Files\dotnet\dotnet.exe
```

Comment: i had added the new value for Path in my enviroment PC where iis is running but the processPath is still showing dotnet.exe

Comment: Of course, it won't change your processPath value. Leave it as is and try to run. It just allow you to use `processPath="dotnet.exe"` instead of `processPath="C:\Program Files\dotnet\dotnet.exe"` So you do not need make any chnages after  publishing

Comment: Unfortunately my application is nort running. I made a mistake when i wrote that the value of processPath of my web config file is "donet.exe". The value is only "donet"

Comment: It doesn't matter. Set `processPath="dotnet"` and add `C:\Program Files\dotnet\dotnet.exe` to Environment Variables. If it doesn't help then describe the error that you get

Comment: it does not help. I'm getting error 502.5 Process failure(Application process failed to start).

Comment: See this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38624453/asp-net-core-1-0-on-iis-error-502-5

Comment: Thank you for your help Megatron. My problem was with access permissions to iis ApplicationPoolIdentity user