# ASP.NET Core 2.0 on IIS error 502.5

Tags: iis, asp.net-core, iis-7.5, asp.net-core-2.0

I install `.net` core 2.0 to my windows server 2008
I have two web project. Both of them work in my PC. But when I publish to my server one project work very well but other give that error

> HTTP Error 502.5 - Process Failure
>
> Application 'MACHINE/WEBROOT/APPHOST/KI-TAP.COM' 
>       with physical root 'C:\HostingSpaces\Reseller1\ki-tap.com\wwwroot\'
>        failed to start process with commandline
>        'dotnet .\ki-tap.dll', ErrorCode = '0x80004005 : 8000808c.

I update my windows server but it still gives the same error.

here is my `program.cs` (I didn't add code here. This is default)

```
  public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            BuildWebHost(args).Run();
        }

        public static IWebHost BuildWebHost(string[] args) =>
            WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .UseStartup<Startup>()
                .Build();
    }
```

and here is my `web.config` (published and default code )

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModule" resourceType="Unspecified" />
    </handlers>
    <aspNetCore processPath="dotnet" arguments=".\ki-tap.dll" stdoutLogEnabled="true" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" />


  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

and here is my startup.cs(I added session configuration)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;

namespace ki_tap
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddMvc();
            services.AddSession();

        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
                app.UseBrowserLink();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
            }

            app.UseStaticFiles();
            app.UseSession();

            app.UseMvc(routes =>
            {
                routes.MapRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Edited:
with @set suggestion, I run that command in windows server 2008 in cmd console

> C:\Program Files (x86)\dotnet\dotnet myProjectPath\project.DLL

it gives the below error. What should I do?

```
 package: 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Antiforgery', version: '2.0.1'
 path: 'lib/netstandard2.0/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Antiforgery.dll'
his assembly was expected to be in the local runtime store as the application
s published using the following target manifest files:
 aspnetcore-store-2.0.3.xml
```

Comment: have you looked on [ASP.NET Core 1.0 on IIS error 502.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38624453/asp-net-core-1-0-on-iis-error-502-5)?

Comment: Thanks @Set .I edited guestion.You can see error in the end of guestion

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You may have the same problem as described [here](https://github.com/aspnet/IISIntegration/issues/476) in aspnet/IISIntegration repo. The solution is to add the following into `.csproj` file:

```
<PropertyGroup>
   <PublishWithAspNetCoreTargetManifest>false</PublishWithAspNetCoreTargetManifest>
</PropertyGroup>
```

And in general, the source of this problem is that the dotnet version on your local computer and the dotnet version on the server are different.

Comment: Thanks it works, I got this error because my development machine get updated to 2.x.x and deployment server was 2.y.y

Comment: I have windows server in AWS EC2 instance that is new. If i install all the .Net Core related things in it like Runtime will it work?