# ASP.NET Core 2.1 IIS hosting error 502.5 - Unable to execute dotnet command to determine cause

Tags: c#, iis, asp.net-core

So I am getting the rather common **HTTP Error 502.5 - Process Failure** now that I've hosted my project on a server VM running Windows Server 2016. While troubleshooting, I've attempted most of the solutions proposed for the same error:

[ASP.NET Core 1.0 on IIS error 502.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38624453/asp-net-core-1-0-on-iis-error-502-5).

Nothing else helped, so I'm looking at the answer that received the most upvotes. This mentions running the following command to receive a more meaningful message describing the error:

> C:\fullpath\dotnet C:\fullpath\PROJECT.dll

I am honestly not sure how to execute that. What I did was navigate to the published project's containing folder on the server through the cmd, and issue the command like so:

> dotnet .\My_Project Integration.dll

But the console prints this in response:

> No executable found matching command "dotnet-.\My_Project"

Notice how the DLL is titled 'My_Project Integration.dll, however the word 'Integration' is absent from the console response. I do not know whether the underscore is to blame here, but any help is appreciated getting the command to run.

And of course, if you know of a solution to the actual 502.5, that is welcome as well.

Comment: Make sure you are in the directory where the dll is located and run dotnet My_Project Integration.dll . The ".\" is what's causing the problem. If I had to guess, the 502.5 is probably due to a mismatching package version, or possibly a out of date hosting bundle on your VM.

Comment: Try enabling logging for the ASP.NET Core Module to get more information about why the process can't start:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/iis/troubleshoot?view=aspnetcore-2.1#aspnet-core-module-stdout-log

Comment: Also when you run your `dotnet` command, put the whole path in quotes.  You have a space in your filename so it needs to be quoted.

Comment: @JustinHelgerson Thanks for all the suggestions. I did put the whole path in quotes and my application started running in the console window. No errors. I also enabled stdout logging and am finding the same message as previously in the console: No executable found matching command "dotnet-.\My_Project". How can I perform the same fix as while launching manually?

Comment: @AndreyBelenkiy Have you checked the system eventviewer log for errors that may be preventing your app from executing via IIS

Comment: You should run something like `dotnet .\My_Project\Integration.dll` so as to give the `dotnet` command a valid path to an assembly. Leaving a space there would confuse the command line and that's why there is an error reported.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've likely got this issue:  https://github.com/aspnet/Home/issues/1931.  The ASP.NET Core IIS Module reads the Web.config to determine what to execute to run the app.

You said running `dotnet ".\My_Project Integration.dll"` worked successfully and enabling stdout showed the same issue of the path being truncated after the space.

Two options:

1. Remove the space from your project (this would be the easiest option)
2. Update your `Web.config`

If you do #2, your Web.config needs to have something like this for the arguments attribute:

```
arguments='".\My_Project Integration.dll"'
```

Comment: Used option 2 to fix the issue entirely. Thank you.